# Context in javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, scope, overriding, self

We are using a oop architecture as the following, and we have a scope problem. We have the 'self' variable for saving the context, but when we call the function 'print' in the overridden class, we are using the 'self' variable instead of 'this', and we cannot override a base method.
Do someone knows how override this methods with this architecture?

```
var baseItem = function() {
var self = {};
    self.a = function () {
        console.log('base');
        return 1;
    };

    self.print = function() {
        return self.a();
    }

    return self;
};

var middleItem = function () {
    var parent = baseItem();
    var self = Object.create(parent);

    return self;
}

var overrided = function () {
    var parent = middleItem();
    var self = Object.create(parent);

    self.a = function() {
        console.log('overrided');
        return 55;
    };

    return self;
}

var obj = overrided();
overrided.print(); // This returns 1 instead 55, as we would want
```

Comment: `this` is not "context," although sadly some people have tried to use the term for that. The word "context" has a specific meaning with regard to JavaScript, and it has nothing whatsoever to do with `this`.

Comment: in short, no, you can't. there's no way to replace the private variable `self` in the first one that the first `self.print` memorizes, unless you made some sort of pass-through argument, or just used `this` properly, like most methods use to become generic.

Comment: If you were using `this.a` in `print`, it would work. This business of trying to avoid `this` is what's biting you.